# Having different settings for each PC the application is ran on

Tags: c#, winforms, settings

I am creating a cash register program that will be distributed via Click-Once (I believe that is the right term, VS built-in packaging). Each PC that runs this software will have different settings for things like credit card processing. How/where do I store these settings so they aren't overwritten every time there is an update and so they can be unique based on the PC it's installed on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is exactly what the built-in application settings are for in WinForms. They allow you to start with a default configuration, which you can then modify on each workstation. Changes will survive upgrades without a problem.

[Here is a tutorial](http://codehill.com/2009/01/saving-user-and-application-settings-in-winforms/).

Comment: I was wondering about that. I wasn't sure if it really worked or not.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like the registry would be good place to put these.

See the [`Microsoft.Win32.Registry`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5f1xf5kf.aspx) class.

> This class provides the set of standard root keys found in the registry on machines running Windows. The registry is a storage facility for information about applications, users, and default system settings. For example, applications can use the registry for storing information that needs to be preserved after the application is closed, and access that same information when the application is reloaded. For instance, you can store color preferences, screen locations, or the size of the window. You can control this data for each user by storing the information in a different location in the registry.

---

Another option, using the built in configuration infrastructure would involve the unique settings being in a file of its own using [`configSource`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.sectioninformation.configsource.aspx). Each computer would have a different file (with the same schema), which will not be updated.

Comment: What class would I look into to do that?

Comment: You wouldn't use the built-in support for application settings in WinForms? The registry seems a bit... old fashioned.

Comment: @JonB - Makes upgrades easy. No need to start copying over settings from one file to another.

Comment: Do you have a better way @JonB?

Comment: I've used application settings in WinForms extensively, and it's never been an upgrade hassle.

Comment: @JonB - For multiple clients that need to have different settings each?

Comment: The suitability for multiple clients is exactly the same as the registry. You would start with default settings and modify from there. I've posted an answer with this suggestion.

Comment: @JonB - Even what you have to add new settings?

Comment: As I recall, there is an `Upgrade` function for that. With any solution, you have to be careful about upgrading per-machine/user settings. From what you're saying, however, it seems like you think the built-in settings functionality should never be used. My understanding is that it is designed for exactly this purpose. And my experience is that it works very well for this purpose.

Comment: @JonB - I have no experience with it, which is why I am asking :)

Comment: Ah. I made the typical mistake of "207K means he is all knowing". It's worth having a look at if you're doing WinForms still. It requires less code than the registry, it supports more datatypes, and WinForms controls can be directly bound to the settings. It's really quite cool.

Comment: @JonB - I really am much of of a web guy, with a limited amount of desktop work (WPF mostly, these days).